# Caret on R spills "unable to find variable "optimismBoot"" error message

Tags: r, r-caret, nnet

I have been testing `caret` on R to test neural network features.
As I run the script below, it was working correctly, this has been starting outputting "unable to find variable "optimismBoot".

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
library(caret)
m<-rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
train_data<-as.data.frame(m)
nnmodel <- train(
  V3 ~ ., 
  data = train_data,
  method = "nnet", 
  preProcess = c('center', 'scale'),
  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"),
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(size=c(1:10), decay=seq(0.1, 1, 0.1)),
  linout = T
)
```

Why?

```
[environment]
Windows 10 64bit
R 3.4.1
RStudio
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue is a caret defect that was repaired in the September 11, 2017 release of caret.  Install the github version of caret with `devtools::install_github('topepo/caret/pkg/caret')`.

See [issue #706](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/706) on the caret github site for details.

regards,

Len

Comment: I consider this to be the best answer as I can keep the latest R version.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Chris. Were you able to complete your analysis?

Comment: Yes, I was able to complete my analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I did not get this problem resolved by reverting to R version 3.3.3. Also, my other computer has R 3.4.0 installed which has no problem with caret. Strange voodoo...
...
Update: The problem could involve the package snow. Switching off parallelization (unloading the doParallel package) resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I think so too. By restarting RStudio, I've resolved problem. It seems a problem of loaded libraries. thank you.