# Caret train function - unable to find variable "optimismBoot"

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret

I'm new to R and RStudio and have been experimenting with predictive modeling.  The following train function works without parallel processing but when I implement doSNOW makeCluster, I get the error shown below related to a variable named "optimismBoot".  I've searched in vain for a resolution, tried installing and uninstalling packages, but nothing works.  Any insight appreciated.

```
 cl <- makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK")

 registerDoSNOW(cl)

 caret.cv <- train(ReturnedToMF ~ .,
                       data = trees.cetstrain,
                       method = "xgbTree",
                       tuneGrid = tune.grid,
                       trControl = cetstrain.control)
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  unable to find variable "optimismBoot"
```

I found the following link on this site but it doesn't really provide a solution to make parallel processing work: [Caret on R spills "unable to find variable "optimismBoot"" error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159844/caret-on-r-spills-unable-to-find-variable-optimismboot-error-message)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a reference to this issue on Caret github page.
They seem to have fixed it lately

See here :
https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/706

In that case, I guess installing caret directly from github should solve the problem .

`devtools::install_github('topepo/caret/pkg/caret')`

See here :
https://github.com/topepo/caret

Follow these steps: (I'm assuming you are using RStudio)

1. Install `devtools` package as usual
2. Run the command `devtools::install_github('topepo/caret/pkg/caret')` and check the output to make sure the package is refreshed from github
3. Restart RStudio/R. The version of caret in package explorer will be same as before, but the package would be using new code
4. To make dead sure it is updated, you can   output the source code of this changed internal function with `caret:::nominalTrainWorkflow` and make sure the following line is in there : `export <- c("optimism_xy")`. If you do it right now, the line would have `optimismBoot` instead of `optimism_xy`

PS:  <strike>Latest version of Caret is dated September 7, 2017. So updating should solve the issue as well.</strike>

Comment: Seems like the fix has happened on September 11, 2017. The package from September 7 (6.0-77) does not have the fix :)

Comment: @armen : damn elapsedTime! :-)  `install_github` is the way forward then

Comment: I take it then that all I can do is wait for a new release of caret?  I currently have version 6.0-77 installed and checking CRAN for updates doesn't find anything newer.  Any idea how often new versions are published?

Comment: @cag. Have you tried installing it using `install_github` ? Install the package `devtools` as usual  and then try the command in my answer. That would 'bypass' cran  and give you the exact  version on github.

Comment: @cag OK, I went ahead and updated  the answer with all the info, and   some more.

Comment: @R.S. Thank you!  Installing from github did it.

Comment: Pleased it helped.

Comment: Updated to latest --  R 3.4.2 and RStudio 1.1.383 -- and updated all packages.  Could not knit a mark down file that worked fine earlier today.  This "optimismBoot" problem was still an issue until I re-downloaded caret from GitHub as described above.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this problem when I updated the packages the new caret version is caret_6.0-77, now I solve it by download the old version of caret package is caret_6.0-76 from the cran archives packages see this link Click [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/caret/)!, and then install the package file locally using Rstudio from the Tools menu and then select install packages it appear dialog box from the pop-menu choose to install from file (.extension)

I hope this helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use the [example from the docs](https://topepo.github.io/caret/parallel-processing.html) for parallel processing.

```
library(parallel)
library(doMC)
# use all cores except one
doMC::registerDoMC(cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1)
```

That's all you have to do, then you can run `train()` and it should be using the number of cores you specified.
I adapted it a bit to dynamically detect number of cores with the `parallel` library.